# $ (f^{-1})'(\zeta) \neq 0 $ holds for every $ \zeta \in \partial D $?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Let $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be simply connected and bounded domain with $ \partial \Omega \in C^2 $, $ D $ denotes the unit disc, $ f $ be the conformal mapping from $\Omega $ to $ D $, then $ (f^{-1})'(\zeta) \neq 0 $ holds for every $ \zeta \in \partial D $?
Could anyone recommend some reference for this proposition?

Comment: See Open Mapping Theorem in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @  Kavi Rama Murthy I am not familiar with complex analysis, could you please tell how can Open Mapping Theorem give this result?